# See commands ran by Portainer

Tags: docker, portainer

How/where to see the commands ran by Portainer when using its graphical interface?

For example, when I start an existing container, I would like to know how it does it. Like in Jetbrain's IDE when it displayed the logs of the git commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Portainer does not directly run commands like `docker ps`, it instead calls the docker REST api like `GET /api/endpoints/1/docker/containers/json?all=1`. If you want to see this, you can sniff traffic on the network "docker0" with for example wireshark.

Comment: Argh, sad :( I would love to learn more of docker with that feature... Thanks for your help